# EF Core does not track entity correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hi I have problem with EF Core insert entity. The problem is that I need to insert new entity with relation to another one which is already existing. I have created the relations with fluent API. I have done this for two times. First I am creating car and adding the last edited by field with Identity user and all works but when I am trying to do the same with another entity it crashes down with

My fluent APi code which works good:

```
 builder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Owner)
            .WithMany(x => x.OwnerCars)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);
```

Here is car entity:

```
public class Car : CarBase
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrailer { get; set; }
    public virtual TrailerType TrailerType { get; set; }
    public virtual int? TrailerTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual string OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

and here is Application user entity

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEditationDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser LastEditedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DeletedDateTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DriverLicenseApplicationUser> DriverLicenses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RideApplicationUser> Rides { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Car> OwnerCars { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Car> EditedCars { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Trailer> EditedTrailers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> EditedCustomers { get; set; }

}
```

To add this entity I only call this function and all works.

```
public Car CreateCar(Car car)
    {
        _context.Cars.Add(car);
        return car;
    }
```

But when I want to save this way this another entity type it shows an error. All steps are same so I do not understand this. Here I am adding the code I use to do that.

```
builder.Entity<Trailer>()
            .HasOne(x => x.TrailerType)
            .WithMany(x => x.Trailers)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TrailerTypeId);
```

Here is Trailer:

```
public class Trailer : CarBase
{
    [Key]
    public int TrailerId { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public virtual TrailerType TrailerType { get; set; }
    public virtual int TrailerTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

and here is traylerTyper:

```
 public class TrailerType:Trackable
{
    //[Key]
    public int TrailerTypeId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Car> TrailerTypeCars { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Trailer> Trailers{ get; set; }
}
```

and the method is the same as the one already mentioned

```
public Trailer CreateTrailer(Trailer trailer)
    {
        trailer.TrailerTypeId = trailer.TrailerType.TrailerTypeId;

        //_context.Attach(trailer.TrailerType);
        var result = _context.Trailers.Add(trailer);
        return result.Entity;
    }
```

When I uncomment the attach it works but I think that I dont have to attach this because I have got the relation based on IDs and the example mentioned first works great. It gives me no sense. So if anyone could give me advice it would be awsome.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TrailerTypes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

It looks like the EF doesnt know that the traylertype entity already exists and is trying to insert the same entity again and the app crashes because it already exists and I am not allowing to insert IDs directly. As I said I have absolutely no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Lazy loading. Propetry from ViewModel is not completly same as property in Database and EF tracks whole graph of property in object and doesn´t recognize that it is the same object. The solution is to work only with IDs instead with whole objects.